# What is a chairleg camstud?

Tags: wood

I am trying to assemble a chair I bought online and cannot find a how-to video for it . The chair leg has a "cam stud" for the 2 screws and the instruction states "make sure the cam studs face out".  I'm not sure what "cam studs" are nor which way "out" is based on the diagram. The chair legs are being installed in the front 2 corners of the chair seat.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you have parts like [these](http://www.falconworkshop.co.uk/Cam_Lock_Image.jpg)? They're typically referred to as cam lock nuts, but I could see the screw part being called a cam stud.

Answer (score 1):

Does your kit contain components that look like these:

[image]

Or these:

[image]

Note that these both types of these studs have a differing type/size of threading on each end.

For your chair leg application in all likelihood the studs to hold on the legs look like the latter type. These are installed with the lag bolt thread end screwed into the end of the chair leg. Since you have a chair kit the installation holes are probably already pre-drilled into the leg at one end from the side corner. Here is a picture that shows a common usage for chair front legs or table legs.

[image]

One way to install the stud into the chair leg is to thread two nuts onto the bolt threaded end of the stud. Then use two wrenches to tighten the two nuts toward each other so that they lock onto the thread. Then use one wrench to screw the lag bolt thread end into the chair leg using one of the nuts as a bolt head. After the stud is screwed into place use the two wrenches to loosen the pair of locked nuts so that they can be removed off the stud.

[image]